# Quotation Mark in ruby regular expression misinterpreted as start of string

Tags: ruby, regex, xcode, syntax-highlighting, macruby

I have a macruby project in xcode, in which I want to replace all the left and right quotes in a string with `~@@~@@~"` and `"~@@~@@~`, respectively. I tested the following code in rubular.com, and it works correctly.

```
string.gsub!(/\B"/, "~@@~@@~\"")
string.gsub!(/\b"/, "\"~@@~@@~")
```

But when I use this in xcode, it interprets the `"` in the regexp as the beginning of the string, and says I have the wrong numer of arguments for `gsub`. I tried escaping the quote:

```
string.gsub!(/\B\"/, "~@@~@@~\"")
string.gsub!(/\b\"/, "\"~@@~@@~")
```

But that also did not work. Thanks for your help.

EDIT: I managed to get the error to go away, it seems it was due to something else. The highlighting is still off, but I can handle that, since it works.

Comment: Try replacing the doble quoted with single: `'~@@~@@~"'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the alternate syntax `%r[\B\"]` work any better? What about `Regexp.new` given a string?